# Get the tcllib version of a installed Tcl system

Tags: tcl

I know you can get the tcl version just using the tcl_version variable, but how you get the version of the tcllib included in the tcl system?  is there any variable or info command to get it?

I know you can go to Tcl install directory and list all entries under lib directory to see the version of tcllib, in my case, using magicsplat in windows I see inside lib directory a directory named tcllib1.20 so I assume the version installed is 1.20  but  I'm looking for a way to consult the version in a more direct way, just asking the system rather to trust on dir naming.

Comment: What does "package require tcllib" return?

Comment: I think tcllib is not a package but a lib (or module), if I try a "package require tcllib" I get "can't find package tcllib"

Comment: What does "package names" return?

Comment: a long list of names ;-)   In the list I can find a tcllibc package and if I require it I get 0.3.15 but I doubt this is the tcllib version because in tcllib repository says current version is 1.21  (and mine seems to be 1.20)

Comment: here https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tcllibc  it's said that tcllibc is a c implementation of parts of tcllib

Comment: OK, so you do have tcllib installed. What is the output of "set auto_path"? Where did you install tcllib?

Comment: C:/Users/XX/AppData/Local/Apps/Tcl86/lib/tcllib1.20    but as I said I would prefer not to rely on a dir name to get the version since it should be installed in a dir like tcllib with no version info

Comment: Apologies. It looks like "package require tcllib" has been deprecated. You will need to pick one of the packages e.g. csv or base64 and check for the version corresponding to the TCLlib version. Not ideal I know

Comment: For example "package require dns" returns 1.4 for 1.19, 1.4.1 for 1.20 and 1.5.0 for 1.21

Comment: ok, far from ideal indeed, but whatever!  thanks for your reply

Comment: @Pep You might want to check out the alternative I added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To document what we discussed, it's not ideal but as `package require tcllib` has been deprecated, you will need to pick one of the child packages e.g. `dns`, `csv` or `base64` and check for the version corresponding to the TCLlib version. See the Readme.txt for the `tcllib` version you are interested in [from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcllib/files/tcllib/); this will tell you which child package versions are in each release.

For example, `package require dns` returns

- 1.4 for 1.19
- 1.4.1 for 1.20
- 1.5.0 for 1.21

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to consult the version in a more direct way

An improvement could be to extract the version info from the auto-loading index script of `tcllib` (`pkgIndex.tcl`). This can be achieved by inspecting the [`auto_path`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.html#M25) and scan it for tcllib`'s index file. For example:

1. Load any `tcllib` module/ package:

```
% package require fileutil
1.16.1
```

This is because `tcllib` will add its installation directory to `auto_path` when the package index gets populated. Besides, and any `tcllib` module will do the job, [`fileutil`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.md) is useful down the road.

2. Process the directories in `auto_path` and expand it to file paths pointing to `pkgIndex.tcl` scripts:

```
% set files [lmap dir $auto_path {set f [file join $dir pkgIndex.tcl]; if {[file exists $f] && [file readable $f]} {set f} else {continue}}]
/path/to/tcl-pkgs/lib/tcllib1.21/pkgIndex.tcl
```

Note that there might be multiple of those paths to pkgIndex.tcl files (e.g., other Tcl packages or because multiple tcllib versions are installed).

3. Scan content of pkgIndex.tcl files for known `tcllib` metadata and generated text (by `tcllib`'s installer).

```
% lindex [fileutil::grep {# Generated by tcllib installer for version} {*}$files] 0
/path/to/tcl-pkgs/lib/tcllib1.21/pkgIndex.tcl:3:# Generated by tcllib installer for version 1.21
```

- [`fileutil::grep`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.md#15): Greps for pkgIndex.tcl files having this static prefix "# Generated by tcllib installer for version" specific to `tcllib`'s `pkgIndex.tcl`. It is generated during tcllib installation and contains the version number (`1.21`)
- The first occurrence of a `tcllib` `pkgIndex.tcl` is most likely the one actually loaded (in presence of multiple installations). Hence: `lindex`.

4. Extract the version number from grep's output.

Comment: I'd prefer to have `tcllib` version number still present in its packages' version specifiers, e.g., by using a [SemVer metadata fragment](https://semver.org/#spec-item-10): `1.16.1+1.21`. This way, a `package require fileutil` (or, similar) would be sufficient, without affecting auto-loading per se. See [TIP 439](https://www.tcl-lang.org/cgi-bin/tct/tip/439.html)